# Почему возвращает html, который вне блока php?

Tags: php

По идее блок html должен попадать под условие if и выполняться - if true.
В данном случае - false, но html возвращает.

```
<?php
    $shop  = "open";
    if ($shop == "close") 
?>

<h3>Этот html-код попадает в блок выполнения php - кода (if true)</h3>

<?php

    echo "Покупаю хлеб";
    echo "Иду домой";
?>
```

Comment: А где дальнейшее условие if?

Comment: фигурные скобки добавь

Comment: А почему вы считаете что вывод HTML в данном случае как-то зависит от PHT-кода?

Comment: Отличный вопрос, кстати :) До меня не сразу дошло

Comment: @PinkTux ну так он и спрашивает - почему не зависит

Answer (score 5, accepted):

писать надо так:

```
<?php
    $shop  = "open";
    if ($shop == "close"):
?>

<h3>Этот html-код попадает в блок выполнения php - кода (if true)</h3>

<?php
    endif;

    echo "Покупаю хлеб";
    echo "Иду домой";
?>
```

это [Альтернативный синтаксис управляющих структур](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php#control-structures.alternative-syntax)

или так:

```
<?php
    $shop  = "open";
    if ($shop == "close") {
?>

<h3>Этот html-код попадает в блок выполнения php - кода (if true)</h3>

<?php
    }

    echo "Покупаю хлеб";
    echo "Иду домой";
?>
```

по обычному стандарту расстановки скобок в управляющей конструкции.

> строго говоря, этот пост не объясняет, почему не работает. – @Ипатьев

Собсн, я этот момент упустил. Но это уже можно посмотреть в соседних ответах участников **[@Ипатев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/643657/191482)** и **[@vp_arth](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/643648/191482)**

Не думаю, что они их удалят))

Comment: Вот, я же говорю, фигурные скобки надо

Comment: @ЕвгенийТупиков с альтернативным синтаксисом не надо

Comment: Блеск! Было интересно, почему без фигурных скобок не работает как надо! Спасибо Вам

Comment: @АлександрЖариченко строго говоря, этот пост не объясняет, почему не работает.

Comment: @Ипатьев потому что надо правильно писать управляющие конструкции вкупе с html? :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, таки потому что точка с запятой.

Comment: При чем здесь HTML

Comment: говоря не строго, этот пост объясняет, как работать с альтернативным синтаксисом в данном случае

Answer (score 4):

Я думаю, надо все-таки явно написать, почему строчка выводится.

Без определения области действия, операторы РНР действуют только на следующий оператор. То есть,

```
if (false) echo 1;
echo 2;
```

разумеется, этот код выведет только 2.
Если же нам надо, чтобы в область действия попало больше операторов, ее надо обозначить явно.

```
if (false) {
    echo 1;
    echo 2;
}
```

Этот код не выведет ничего.

Но остается вопрос, почему РНР не воспринял оператор вывода HTML, который, вроде бы, идет самым первым после условия. Ответ на этот вопрос дал vp_arth - потому что закрывающий тег РНР действует так же и как ограничитель оператора. То есть в итоге у автора получилось условие, действующее на пустой оператор:

```
if ($shop == "close") ;
#                    ^ оператор видишь? И я нет. А он есть!
```

и дальнейший код уже под его действие не попал.

Answer (score 3):

Конструкция `?>` предполагает автоматическую подстановку **точки с запятой**.
Ваш код аналогичен следующему:

```
<?php
    $shop  = "open";
    if ($shop == "close") 
    ; // <- Условие распространяется только на этот пустой оператор

    echo '<h3>Этот html-код попадает в блок выполнения php - кода (if true)</h3>';

    echo "Покупаю хлеб";
    echo "Иду домой";
```

Вам следует явно определить область действия оператора if:

- С помощью фигурных скобок: `<?if ($cond) {?>Text<?}?>`
- С помощью [альтернативного синтаксиса](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php): `<?if($cond):?>Text<?endif?>`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский [это шутка?](https://3v4l.org/vIeja)

Comment: https://3v4l.org/vIeja

Comment: )))))))))))))))

Comment: @Ипатьев неа. ругался phpfiddle :(  .... вот он http://phpfiddle.org/ нехороший

Comment: Даже он ругался просто на отсутствие закрывающего тега в самом конце(непонятно зачем, правда)

Comment: @vp_arth угу... ну бывает, апшипся и чо?))

Comment: Понял почему. Он его через `eval("?>$code<?php ...")` прогоняет

Comment: Запомню. Спасибо Вам